# NodeMCU gpio triggering incorrectly

Tags: lua, esp8266, gpio, nodemcu

I'm attempting to read IR information from a NodeMCU running Lua 5.1.4 from a master build as of 8/19/2017.

I might be misunderstanding how GPIO works and I'm having a hard time finding examples that relate to what I'm doing.

```
pin = 4
pulse_prev_time = 0
irCallback = nil

function trgPulse(level, now)
  gpio.trig(pin, level == gpio.HIGH and "down" or "up", trgPulse)

  duration = now - pulse_prev_time
  print(level, duration)

  pulse_prev_time = now
end

function init(callback)
  irCallback = callback
  gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT)
  gpio.trig(pin, 'down', trgPulse)
end

-- example
print("Monitoring IR")
init(function (code)
  print("omg i got something", code)
end)
```

I'm triggering the initial interrupt on low, and then alternating from low to high in `trgPulse`. In doing so I'd expect the levels to alternate from 1 to 0 in a perfect pattern. But the output shows otherwise:

```
1   519855430
1   1197
0   609
0   4192
0   2994
1   589
1   2994
1   1198
1   3593
0   4201
1   23357
0   608
0   5390
1   1188
1   4191
1   1198
0   3601
0   3594
1   25147
0   608
1   4781
0   2405
1   3584
0   4799
0   1798
1   1188
1   2994
```

So I'm clearly doing something wrong or fundamentally don't understand how GPIO works. If this is expected, why are the interrupts being called multiple times if the low/high levels didn't change? And if this does seem wrong, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that platform but are you sure you're not getting noise on the IR input? The first thing I'd do is disconnect it and connect the input to ground and see what happens. Also not sure for that platform but on some microcontrollers changing the interrupt edge doesn't work well in an interrupt routine, if you have spare inputs maybe connect both to the IR receiver and set one for each edge.

Comment: what do you mean with read IR information? what did you connect to pin 4?

Comment: I doubt I'm getting noise, I only see data interrupt changes immediately after tapping a button on my remote. It lasts for the duration of my button press, so it seems fairly stable.

I've got an IR receiver connected to pin 4.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm clearly doing something wrong or fundamentally don't understand how GPIO works

I suspect it's a bit a combination of both - the latter may be the cause for the former.

My explanation may not be 100% correct from a mechanical/electronic perspective (not my world) but it should be enough as far as writing software for GPIO goes. Switches tend to bounce between 0 and 1 until they eventually settle for one. A good article to read up on this is https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/switch-bounce-how-to-deal-with-it/. The effect can be addressed with hardware and/or software.

Doing it with software usually involves introducing some form of delay to skip the bouncing signals as you're only interested in the "settled state". I documented the NodeMCU Lua function I use for that at https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/59563e791effa4acb65f

```
-- inspired by https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/blob/master/tutorials/introduction-to-gpio-api.md
-- and http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=4833&start=5#p29127
local pin = 4    --> GPIO2

function debounce (func)
    local last = 0
    local delay = 50000 -- 50ms * 1000 as tmr.now() has μs resolution

    return function (...)
        local now = tmr.now()
        local delta = now - last
        if delta < 0 then delta = delta + 2147483647 end; -- proposed because of delta rolling over, https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/issues/2
        if delta < delay then return end;

        last = now
        return func(...)
    end
end

function onChange ()
    print('The pin value has changed to '..gpio.read(pin))
end

gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT, gpio.PULLUP) -- see https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/pull/1
gpio.trig(pin, 'both', debounce(onChange))
```

Note: `delay` is an empiric value specific to the sensor/switch!

Comment: Sounds very likely. I'll give that a try!